# Angular Service to Share string from App component to other compooents

Tags: angular

How do I send the string from app.component.ts to the service and have the service send the string to the component.

I am using the Amplify Authentication and get the authstatus string to let me know if a user is signed in. I want to share this status with other components. This my attempt at creating a service, but need help.  I am sending the string from app.component.ts and forwarding it from the service to auth.component and others.

````
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthStatusService {

  authStatus: string;

  authStatusChange: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();

  constructor()  {
      this.authStatusChange.subscribe((value) => {
          this.authStatus = value
      });
  }

}```
````

Comment: And the questions is?

Comment: Thanks. How do I get the string from app.component and how to send it to home.component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to push the value to the observable. `authStatus` variable is negligible. Try the following

AuthStatusService

```js
export class AuthStatusService {
  authStatusChange: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();

  constructor() { }

  public getAuthStatus(): Observable<string> {
    return this.authStatusChange.asObservable();
  }

  public setAuthStatus(status: string) {
    this.authStatusChange.next(status);
  }
}
```

app.component.ts

```js
login() {
  this.service.login().subscribe(
    response => {
      // handle login
      this.authStatusService.setAuthStatus(response.status);
    },
    error => {
      // handle error
    }
}
```

child.component.ts

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.authStatusService.getAuthStatus().subscribe(
    status => {
      // got login status
    }
  );
}
```

This way every child component will get the login status whenever a new login status is pushed in from the app component.

Comment: The return is necessary for the observable.

 public getAuthStatus(): Observable<string> {
    return this.authStatusChange.asObservable();
  }

Comment: Yeah missed it, added in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution will be using service as store for storing AuthStatus.
Please find below solution:

In your service declare one private variable and write getters and setters for it in service as below:

```
private authStatus :string;

//this method will be called for updating value of authstatus
setAuthStatus(value : string){
this.authStatus = value;
}

//you can fetch this method from any compononent to get the value of authstatus
getAuthStatus(){
return this.authStatus;
}
```

In your case,

in app.component.ts call **setAuthStatus** method and set value

```
this.service.setAuthStatus("your value");
```

in other components call **getAuthStatus** method and fetch the value

```
let authStatus = this.service.getAuthStatus();
```

Comment: jam66125 if it helped you, Please mark it as answer so others can use it when visits this page

Comment: Don't I have to subscribe to it authStatus?

Comment: you wont be needing that as it is returning only string not an observable

Comment: @sankret The string variable can change if one logs out

Comment: If you update it from app.componet.ts then it will change